# Where do commas fit in with regards to a list of inquiring/exclaiming quotations?

Tags: commas, lists, quotations

If one were to list several exclamatory quotations within a single sentence, where and how do commas fit in?

For instance;
   "When children are on my lawn I like to yell, "Get away you mangy kids!", "I'm going to call the police again!", Here comes the garden hose!", "I know where you live!", or something to that effect."

Do the commas belong outside the quotation marks, inside following the exclamation mark, or do they not belong at all?

Comment: We probably need to consider re-titling the duplicate question to make it easier to find.

Comment: Yes, it seems re-titling is in order. I found several answers to similar questions, but not to this one in particular.